# Python Requests / HTTPX - Authenticate All Redirected URL - How To

Tags: python, api, http, authentication, redirect

I wonder if there is a way to authenticate each redirected URL when working with Python modules such as `httpx` or `requests`?

**Problem Statement**

I am trying to connect to an API endpoint under the company network. Due to the company's cyber security measures, the API endpoint will be randomly masked with a company proxy, which causes the `307 Redirect` status code.

my current code snippet looks like the below:

```
import httpx

api_url = 'https://demo.vizionapi.com/carriers'

head = {
  'X-API-Key':'API KEY'
}

response = httpx.get(url=api_url, verify='supporting_files/cacert.pem',
          headers=head, auth=('my username', 'my password'),
          follow_redirects=True)
```

With above code, I received the `401 authentication needed` error (But `auth` has been  passed). This error will only happen when redirection occurs due to the company proxy.

Question:

My assumption is the authentication is only being passed into the first URL not the redirected URL. Therefore, I wonder if anyone know how I can use the same `auth` parameter for all URLs (direct & redirect)?

Any suggestion will be deeply appracaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what requests behavior with regards to auth during redirect is, but the first solution to come to mind is to manually follow the redirects yourself.  Put your request in a loop that checks for the 3xx response codes, and handle auth however you want to.